# Upgrading Cordova 1.9 to 2.0 version

Tags: ios, cordova

I need to upgrade my application which is using Cordova 1.8 version to Cordova 2.0 version. I followed the steps mentioned in the http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html. My application's running for 1.9 but when am trying to upgrade it to 2.0 version am not able to find 'Preprocessor Macro' in build setting.

Also I am not able to find 'CordovaLib' folder, but in the 10th step they have mentioned related to PreprocessorMacro which am not able to find.

Comment: What are your motivation to upgrade? Does creating a new project with the last version of Cordova an option?

Comment: yes i want to increase the performance of my app by upgrading cordova in the existing project. i actually want to upgrade it to 2.7 but i came to know dat its better to upgrade it incrementally. am doing the same. but got stuck in upgrading 1.9 to 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you main motivation seems to be up to date with the **last version of Cordova**, I would recommend to **create a new clean project** with Cordova 2.8 and **import your html files** in the www folder.

Upgrading version by version is painful and you will not get any benefits from it. However, **you might not get any performance improvement** but you will get a **better support** from the community.

Comment: but upgrading cordova directly from 1.8 to 2.7 may effect the functionality of my app rite? and if am upgrading directly only importing the html file will work or shud do any other changes? plz specify if der s any minor change also.. thanks..

Comment: 1. Upgrade to 2.8, 2. Check if anything fails, 3. Fix the potential issues

Comment: hi.. after creating new project of cordova 2.7 where shud i specify my app url in xcode? plz help.. am new to this cordova framework..

Comment: Please read the Getting Started guide: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS . Please also accept my answer if you are satisfied. That's how stackoverflow works.